# Comparing the fornats between sets of strings in PHP

Tags: php

Say I have two strings

```
$string1 = 'foo bar 1,5,6 things';
$string2 = 'example 5,2,3 potato';
```

I'm trying to find a way in php to compare the format of the two strings and split them into an array so for the example the result would be

```
$string1 = array('foo bar', '1,5,6', 'things');
$string2 = array('example', '5,2,3', 'potato');
```

Is there a way of doing this in PHP?

Comment: You'll need to explain the exact rules for this - why is `foo bar` considered the same as `example` when there's a space, but other instances of spaces are considered as separators?

Comment: In this example suppose that I would know for definite that the length of the array for the result is 3. 'foo bar' would fit more in the same column as 'example' than it would as '1,5,6' as the two columns '1,5,6' and '5,2,3' have the same format

What I'm trying to achieve is splitting the strings where it finds there's an area in the same/a similar place with the same format

Comment: @MichaelRennison - I've already answered based on the example input you provided in your question but I just saw your comment above - am I reading extra context here - that you don't know if the strings will have a comma-delimited grouping of digits in the middle?

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to do is find if in two strings there is a similar format. 

I don't know if I'm making any sense by what i'm asking but the idea is essentially that the strings could be rows from a table, and I'm trying to fit the string to the number of columns in the table based on the position of unique formats

Comment: @MichaelRennison - When you say rows from a table, what do you mean? A database table, a HTML table or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Given your example input and assuming that the comma-delimited list of digits can be considered the "delimiter", you can split on that with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`; e.g:

```php
$split = preg_split('/\s+([\d,]+)\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Example implementation:

```
<?php

$strings = [
  'foo bar 1,5,6 things',
  'example 5,2,3 potato',
];

$stringsSplit = array_map(function (string $string) {
  return preg_split('/\s+([\d,]+)\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
}, $strings);

print_r($stringsSplit);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo bar
            [1] => 1,5,6
            [2] => things
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => example
            [1] => 5,2,3
            [2] => potato
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)